# Making like button change color after user click it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This wouldn't be hard for me to solve if i didn't had 2 same id's for each element

I have image with it's own id in database
this is the like button

```
<a id='$id' class='fas fa-angle-up $voteup' onclick='vote(\"up\",this);'></a>
```

and this is the dislike button

```
 <a id='$id' class='fas fa-angle-down $votedown' onclick='vote(\"down\",this);'></a>
```

in php i have made that both button ids = same because it's images unique id which is in database latter on based on that ID it being posted to database via this code

```
function vote(vote, val) {
    var params = {"vote": vote, "id": val.id};
    $.ajax({
        data:  params,
        url:   'vote.php',
        type:  'post',
        success:  function (response) {
            // code
        }
    });            
}
```

others told me it's wrong to use same id for 2 elements i think it can be solved if someone could just give me code 
find class where class = angle-up and id = 1 change class to checked

i could make that both id aren't same but then i should need to store that id in other place and then get it via code and i have no idea how to do that so this is more easier for me

Comment: IDs must be unique. Use a class or two different IDs  - `$("a.$voteup")`and `$("a.$votedown")` should work

Comment: Others would be correct as `id`s are meant to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

IDs must be unique. Use a class or two different IDs -

```
$("a.$voteup")
```

and

```
$("a.$votedown")
```

should work

but this is recommended

```js
function setActive($but) {
  $(".vote").removeClass("active");
  $but.addClass("active")
}


$(".vote").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $but = $(this);
  var params = {
    "vote": this.id === "voteup" ? "up" : "down",
    "id": $(this).closest("div").attr("id")
  };
  setActive($but); // remove when ajax is available
  console.log("about to vote",params)
  $.ajax({
    data: params,
    url: 'vote.php',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(response) {
      setActive($but);
     },
     error: function(jxhr) { console.lig("error", jxhr)
      }
  });
});
```

```css
#voteup.active { background-color: green }
#votedown.active { background-color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div id="$id">
  <a id='voteup'   class='fas fa-angle-up vote'></a>
  <a id='votedown' class='fas fa-angle-down vote'></a>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm i don't really understand this if i will not use id ad image id then how should i know for which image like was pressed?

Comment: i added image id to another div in that div there are a for like and a for dislike and they both have different id's how can i get id of that div after pressing on one of a?

Comment: <div id='$id' class='area-vote'>
        <a id='1' class='fas fa-angle-up $voteup' onclick='vote(\"up\",this);'></a>
        <a id='2' class='fas fa-angle-down $votedown' onclick='vote(\"down\",this);'></a>

now i need to get id from that area-vote class how to do that?

Comment: Works here. Sorry.  - I see from your comment you did not change your HTML to reflect my HTML - remove the onclick and assign it as I did

Comment: Also the FontAwesome I use does not seem to have the angle thingies

Comment: maybe i can add you to discord or somewhere? so i can post code normally

Comment: Any errors in the console? Press F12. I’m offline for 2 hours now

Comment: Add errror handling to the Ajax

Comment: no idea how to do that.. sorry the previous code i had i did understand 100% of it but with ours only 60 - 70% still im not sure how this ajax 100% work

Comment: See my update. Gotta go offline for a few hours. Look in my profile how to contact me, perhaps I need to see your site

Comment: If we comment enough here, we get a chat request

Comment: as in a few comments time

Comment: I hope. There really should be a link

Comment: But I do not see it

Comment: Perhaps you need to answer too

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)` to target the clicked button, without need for an `id` or even a class :

```js
$("button").click( function(){ $(this).toggleClass("clicked") })
```

```css
.clicked{
 background : chartreuse; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
```

Also, avoid using inline `onclick=`. Use jQuery to bind click events.

Comment: He'd likely not want to toggle this class when he has two links.

Answer (score 0):

`id` must be unique to reference a DOM element. You can either use different ids, or use a class.

```js
function vote(vote, id) {
  console.log(vote, id);
}
```

```css
.daddy {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#btn1 {
  height: 3em;
  width: 10em;
  color: white;
  background-color: #444444;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#btn2 {
  margin-left: 1em;
  height: 3em;
  width: 10em;
  color: white;
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="daddy">
  <div id="btn1" onclick='vote("up", this.id);'>UP</div>

  <div id="btn2" onclick='vote("down", this.id);'>DOWN</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ".classname" to change color.

```
$(".fas fa-angle-up $voteup").click(function(){
    $(this).css( "background-color", "red" );

 });
```